# download file from google drive using R

Tags: csv, download, google-drive-api

I have tried the recommendations to read a csv file in google drive. I write click on the file to get the sharable file link.

I have tried each of these 4 methods: (I have substituted ZZZZ for what I get as the link when I right-click on the file name).

`x <- curl("https://drive.google.com/open?id=ZZZZ") data <- read.csv(x,skip=5,stringsAsFactors = F)`

`id <- "ZZZZ" data <- read.csv(sprintf("https://drive.google.com/open?id=%s&export=download",id),skip=5,stringsAsFactors = F)`

`data <- read.csv("https://drive.google.com/open?id=ZZZZ",skip=5,stringsAsFactors = F)`

`sURL <- sprintf("https://drive.google.com/open?id=%s&export=download",id) con <- curl(sURL); con2 <- read.csv(con,skip=5,stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532206/use-r-to-download-an-individual-shared-file-from-a-shared-google-drive-directo

Answer (score 0):

There is a great package 'gsheet' (God bless the author).
1. Open your file in google drive as google sheet. 
2. Then make your file public (available to anyone who clicks the link). 
3. Then use this code in R:

```
install.packages('gsheet')  
library(gsheet) 
data <- gsheet2tbl('https://drive.google.com/open?id= COPY HERE YOUR ID LINK')
```